# Why is my form marked dirty when manually set a control to pristine in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created this directive:

```
app.directive("date", ['$filter', function ($filter) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attributes, controller) {          
            scope.$watch(function () {
                return controller.$modelValue;
            },
            function (newVal, oldVal) {
                if (newVal !== oldVal && newVal) {
                    var format = attributes.date || "dd-MM-yyyy";
                    var parsedDate = new Date(newVal);

                    parsedDate = $filter('date')(newVal, format);

                    controller.$setViewValue(parsedDate);
                    controller.$setPristine();
                    controller.$render();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}])
```

I this directive like this:

```
<form name='myForm'>
    Date: <input type="text" data-ng-model="contract.StartDate" name="StartDate" date />
</form>
```

In my scope I have a function which determines the state of the save button:

```
scope.canSave = function () {
    return scope.contractForm.$valid && scope.contractForm.$dirty;
}
```

As you can see in the code snippet of the `date` directive, I set `controller.$setPristine()`, however this action is not seen by the form controller, because `form.$dirty` is set to `true`, but when I check `form.StartDate.$dirty` it is set to `false`.

How is this possible and how can I make sure / force that `form` sees that `StartDate` **is not** dirty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find a solution in the form of parsers and formatters:

```
app.directive("date", ['$filter', function ($filter) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attributes, controller) {
            controller.$parsers.unshift(function (value) {
                if (!value) {
                    return;
                }

                var format = attributes.date || "dd-MM-yyyy";
                return $filter('date')(value, format);
            })

            controller.$formatters.unshift(function (value) {
                if (!value) return;

                var format = attributes.date || "dd-MM-yyyy";
                return $filter('date')(value, format);
            })
        }
    }
}])
```

Comment: Your answer provides a workaround; it doesn't answer your question though. I would call this a bug in Angular (this same issue happens with 1.4.8). Here's a Plunkr demonstrating the issue simply: https://plnkr.co/edit/6noEtj6vbMkqxiKK6Yp7?p=preview